# Images not Displaying in MVC View

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-4, foreach, viewbag

I am trying to display all images in folder to my View .
But Images are not loading to my view
Here is my controller code .

```
  string directory1 = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\MogasImages\\";
  ViewBag.Images = Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory1)
                            .Select(fn => directory1 + Path.GetFileName(fn));
   return View();
```

Here is my View code (.cshtml)

```
@foreach(var image in (IEnumerable<string>)ViewBag.Images)
 {
   <label>Hello</label>

   <img src="@Url.Content(image)" alt="Hejsan" />
 }
```

Here is my ViewBag image source 
"C:\Users\karthik.mushyam\AppData\Roaming\MogasImages\2b0ac2b0-933a-4737-bbb4-a47d25224a4f.Jpeg"

Like this i have 4 images am seeing in Quickwatch and in loop but image is not displaying in view where as i have 4 images loop is repeating 4 times label is loading .

Hope for the best ..

Comment: you have to give relative path not absolute in html, and ``@Url.Content()`` also works with relative path,try like :``string directory1 =  "~/MogasImages/";``

Comment: Thanks @Ehsan Sajjad